# Google Piechart Tooltip when enableInteractivity disabled

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I want to show Google Pie Chart with tooltip. But, interactivity (like click) not required.

But, enableInteractivity = false removes toolTip by default. Is there anyway to show toolTip when enableInteractivity = false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enableInteractivity` must be `true` for tooltips to work

but you can *"cancel"* the `'select'` event by setting an empty selection
`chart.setSelection([]);`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task',     'Hours per Day'],
      ['Percent',  10],
      ['Rest',     90],
    ]);
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
      chart.setSelection([]);
    });
    chart.draw(data);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Works Great..! Thanks